# открывать нужный таб при переходе на страницу

Tags: javascript, html

задача стоит в том, что у нас на главной странице есть табы, `<div class="tab__item" id="tab1>tab 1</div`> и `<div class="tab__item" id="tab2">tab 2</div>` и чтобы на эти табы мы могли переходить по ссылкам с других страниц, например https://mainpage/#tab2 - как можно сделать чтобы при переходе на второй или третий таб он открывался? так как сейчас при переходе всегда открыт первый таб

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно это оработать в js по domready:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    if('#tab2' === window.location.hash) {
        //скрываем первый таб, открываем второй
    }
    //else if() тут #таб3 итд
});
```